# JOINS in Debezium : MySQL to Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, sql, database, elasticsearch, debezium

I've been trying to set up a MySQL to Elasticsearch data pipeline for real-time data replication.
The MySQL database has around **10 different tables that are highly normalized**. But in Elasticsearch, I'm in need to have all of the data from these tables in a single index, which would be similar to the output from a big compound JOIN query. Tried a lot to find out, please help

(Changing the DB schema isn't feasible as there are a lot of other dependent services. )

For example :

**Input from MySQL:**

```
Table: main_profile
+--------+------+
|  name  | city |  
+--------+------+
| Edward |    1 | 
| Jake   |    9 |
+--------+------+
```

```
Table: city_master
+---------+----------+
| city_id |   name   |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | New York |
|      9  | Tampa    |
+---------+----------+
```

**Document stored in Elasticsearch:**

```
{
   "0": {
      "name": "Edward",
      "city": "New York"
   },
   "1": {
      "name": "Jake",
      "city": "Tampa"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Kafka Streams to do aggregation from two different topics to build a unfied message. Please check an example for Debezium source https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/kstreams

The target is MongoDB in the example but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Could you please add more detail to it?